# Joint probability $P(X>0, Z>-X)$ for $X,Z \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

> Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Z \sim N(0,1)$ be independent normal random variables. Find the probability $P(X>0,Z>-X)$.

This is apparently an elementary calculation but I struggle to understand it. It is given that $X$ and $Z$ are independent but the limit of $Z$ depends on $X$ which is the source of my confusion.

First of all, could we write
$P(X>0,Z>-X)=P(X>0)P(Z>-X)$? If yes, then I can simply proceed as
$$P(X>0,Z>-X) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\phi(x)\,dx \int_{-x}^{\infty}\phi(s)\,ds.$$ But something looks odd. Is this the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: If $(X,Z)\sim f_{XZ}$ then $$P(X>0,Z>-X)=\int_0^{\infty} \int _{-x}^{\infty}f_{XZ}(x,z)dzdx$$ Independence tells information about $f_{XZ}$, namely that this joint density factors as $$f_{XZ}(x,z)=f_X(x)f_Z(z)$$

Comment: You should also note that $$P(Z>-X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-x}^{\infty}f_{XZ}(x,z)dzdx$$ This probability needs to be written as a double integral, not a single one.

Comment: @FelixMarin: $X$ and $Z$ are $N(0,1)$ random variables and can assume negative values. In fact, $P(X<0)=P(Z<0)=1/2$

Comment: @MatthewPilling I'm sorry. I guess I read $U$ instead of $N$. My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comments, the fact that $X$ and $Z$ are iid $N(0,1)$ random variables tells us that the joint density of $(X,Z)$ (namely $f_{XZ}$) factors as $$f_{XZ}(x,z)=f_{X}(x)f_{Z}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\bigg({-\frac{x^2+z^2}{2}}\bigg)$$ In order to evaluate an expression like $P(X>0,Z>-X)$ you need to integrate your joint density $f_{XZ}(x,z)$ over the region $\mathcal{R}$ in the $(x,z)-$plane given by $$\mathcal{R}=\{(x,z)\in \mathbb{R}^2\big|x>0,z>-x\}$$ This means $$P(X>0,Z>-X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-x}^{\infty}f_{XZ}(x,z)dzdx=\frac{3}{8}$$ On the other hand, if we wanted to compute $P(Z>-X)$ we would have to integrate our joint density $f_{XZ}$(x,y) over the region $$\mathcal{S}=\{(x,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2\big|z>-x\}$$ giving us $$P(Z>-X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-x}^{\infty}f_{XZ}(x,z)dzdx=\frac{1}{2}$$ Note that $P(X>0)=\frac{1}{2}$ and so $$P(X>0,Z>-X)=\frac{3}{8}\neq \frac{1}{4}=P(X>0)P(Z>-X)$$

Comment: Accepted the answer. Better late than never ;)

Comment: lol I don't even remember doing this but thanks!

Comment: I know it has been a long time but I'm just wondering how you arrived at $3/8$ for that integral. Is it an obvious thing or are there more steps involved?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X,Y$ be independent and identically distributed symmetric continuous RVs.

Let $p=P( \underset{=A}{\underbrace{X>0,X+Y>0}})=P(\underset{=B}{\underbrace{X>0,X+Y>0}})$.

Then $A\cup B = \{X+Y >0\}$ and $A\cap B = \{X>0,Y>0\}$, so that $P(A\cup B) = \frac 12$  as $X+Y$ is a continuous symmetric RV, and $P(A \cap B) =  P( X>0)P(Y>0) = \frac 14$.

Use this to get

$$\frac 12 = P(A \cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) = 2 p - \frac 14,$$

giving $p=\frac38$.